# Memory leak in AVAudioPlayer with arc enabled

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, avaudioplayer, instruments

**ARC** is enabled. Instrument is showing memory leak.
Any solution ?

Here is my code:

```cs
- (void) onPlayButtonClicked
{
    NSString *title = @"Pause";

if (isPlay) {
    [player stop];
    player.delegate = nil;
    title = @"Play";
}
else
{
    player = [[ReaderGlobals audioPlayer] initWithContentsOfURL:mSoundPath error:nil];
    player.delegate = self;
    [player play];
}

isPlay ^= true;
[mButtonPlay setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

`ReaderGlobals` is a singleton class and `[ReaderGlobals audioPlayer]` returns a single instance of `AVAudioPlayer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your singleton `[ReaderGlobals audioPlayer]` is returning an instance then you should not need to call `initWithContentsOfURL:error:` on it. That is, you're telling us that the `AVAudioPlayer` has already been allocated (retainCount increased to one) and "inited". So, you should just set what needs to be set on the existing returned instance. Don't call init again.

As a general best-practice, you should never call init on an object more than once. While it won't increase the retainCount (alloc does), it may re-create/ reset internal ivars which may cause existing values to be leaked.

As a general rule, you should use a setter to reset any values to new values (in your case the URL). However, `AVAudioPlayer` doesn't have a setter for the URL so you will have to create a new `AVAudioPlayer` instance altogether whenever you wish to apply a different URL. That's how it's intended to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Player instance is created each time ypu press play button. But it is not released. Make player a Property. After stoping the player do

```
self.player = nil;
```

THis will release player every time you stop azuming player object is a light weight object.